# I can't find where a string is getting defined -- any tricks to find its source?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using:

- Rails 3.2x
- Spree 1.2
- Ruby 1.9.3x

I'm trying to edit the title of one of my pages, and I cannot find where it is getting defined. It is showing up in my base ERB file as 'title', but that name is sufficiently generic to make it next to impossible to find where it is defined.

I have prodded everywhere I can think, I've tried searching for "title =", but nothing is working. I tried calling `source_location` on it, but that appears to only work on methods.

Any tricks for finding where a variable is defined?

Comment: Have you checked your application layout?

Comment: Application layout is where the yield is.

Comment: @theTinMan, the string is in a var called 'title' -- which shows up thousands of times in our code.

Comment: And you can't find the actual *text* of the title anywhere? Don't search for the variable, search for the text in the title. It has to be defined somewhere.

Comment: I suggest looking up "set page title rails" in Google. I don't know off the top of my head what it is, but I believe that Rails has a hook for setting page titles.

Comment: I tried searching for parts of the title -- problem is that it is created from a mixture of product names, a site config, and something else.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of an elegant way. A dumb-but-probably-effective way would be to dump stack trace in your erb, then see what those locations are doing and if `title` is defined there. It has to enter somewhere between the start of program and invoking your erb.

Answer (score 1):

When *I* can't find something, I use `grep -ri some_string .` at the command-line to recursively search all the content of the directory.

It's also a good tactic to let your editor search all the source code, since the ones worth using have the ability to search through all files in a directory.

---

> it is created from a mixture of product names, a site config, and something else

An alternate trick is to add a HTML-comment section in your ERB file, and put the pertinent information for the components used to create the title into that section. Then, let the pages be generated and look inside the page's content to determine what table and row ID it is, the site_config filename, etc.

You really should be able to figure it out based on the parts that are concatenated to build the title and then search your database or files. That information isn't magically created out of thin air by Rails; Someone had to tell Rails how to define the title. But, people move on, or they don't document correctly, so try the embedded information trick.

Comment: The variable is called 'title'. There are thousands of instances of that word showing up in our code.